# Input data length

Tags: javascript

The problem is that I don't understand how to substitute two symbols with one by looking at the input data length.

I have two arrays e.g.

```
var first = ["AA", "B"];
var second = ["G", "D"];
```

Two symbols in the first array AA should be replaced by G from the second array.

I tried the following:

```
var length = this.length;
var char;
var index;
var answer = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char = this[ i ];
        index = first.indexOf( char );
        answer += ( index != -1 ) ? second[ index ] : char;
    }
```

but the problem did not resolved - I easily convert B into D, but not AA into G. How to look at the input data length and then show how many characters to advance, i.e. how to replace AA with G?

The expected outcome is to convert AA into G. But I don't want to use .replace() method. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `this`? A string where you want to apply the transformation? Is there a good reason why don't you want to use the `replace` method?

Comment: It is a length of a string where I want to apply the transformation.

Comment: And I don't know how to change .replace(method) to work in the way that I need.

Answer (score 2):

Using [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can override the value. Make an iteration over `first` array and replace by `second` array element if the first array element length is greater than 1.

```js
var first = ["AA", "B"];
var second = ["G", "D"];

const res = first.map((item, i) => item.length > 1 ? second[i] : item )

console.log(res)
```